# How can I compile openssl with conan using more than one core?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl, conan

We have been using Conan to build most of our dependencies for some time now.
It works great but when we update one of the dependency to the latest version, Conan recompiles it using a single core and this can take quite some time on my laptop.

**How can I do the compilation using all the cores my machine has ?**

A general answer would be appreciated but if any specific hack exists for windows, I would be happy too.

Currently my command line looks like this:

```
conan install "C:/Conan/Conan.txt" --build "missing" -s "build_type=Debug" -s "compiler.runtime=MTd"
```

It looks like I am missing some magic incantation like `-s compiler.multithread=true`, but I cannot find any example of this issue anywhere in the doc and Google didn't help either.

Comment: Conan got the new ``conf`` item ``tools.build:jobs`` that by default will use the available cores, so all modern build-system integrations should use it. I suspect your dependencies maybe have not updated yet to the ``XXXToolchain`` generators like ``CMakeToolchain``?

Comment: It would be better to ask this in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, which is the official support channel for Conan, can be used for questions too. It is very important to report the Conan version too, Conan 2 is more than 1 year old now, so it will be assumed the default.

Comment: @drodri As a matter of fact we are still using Conan 1 until [this issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/16402) is fixed.

Comment: If it invokes msbuild then to it you perhaps need to add maxcpucount switch somehow.

Comment: @Arnaud the openssl is working with Conan 2.x since last year. Please, update your local copy with `conan install --update -r conancenter --requires=openssl/3.2.1`

Comment: @uilianries Thank you for closing the issue ! I was stupidely waiting for a fixed issue to be fixed :)

Comment: @Arnaud sorry delaying to update that. You still can find supported recipes with Conan 2.x by running the command `conan search <package_name_without_version>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Conan 2.x should use all cores available in your machine as the number of jobs, but in case you want to directly say how many jobs should be used, you can set it directly in Conan configuration:

```
tools.build:jobs: Default compile jobs number -jX Ninja, Make, /MP VS (default: max CPUs)
```

https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/global_conf.html#introduction-to-configuration

So, you can add it directly to your profile:

```
[settings]
os=Windows
...
[conf]
tools.build:jobs=8
```

Or, you can pass it directly by command line (it will override the value from your profile):

```
conan install conanfile.txt -c tools.build:jobs=4 --build=missing
```